# Continuous add number with long tap when press button

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello everyone i have a question how i can when i pressed button with long tap my number must to add continuous. 
Like if i pressed he must to add "1,2,3,4,5,6" continuos up to 59.
If someone could help me with that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to keep track of different control states of button. You could add target for three different **UIControlEvent**'s, like **UIControlEventTouchDown**, **UIControlEventTouchUpInside**, **UIControlEventTouchUpOutside**. The touch down event is received when touch starts and other two events tell you that the touch has exited. In between these states, you could count the value and change some text.

```
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchStarted:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchExited:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchExited:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];


- (void)touchStarted:(id)sender
{
  self.touchInProgress = YES;

 /* start your counting operation and do it until the value of touchInProgress BOOL is YES */
}

- (void)touchExited:(id)sender
{
  self.touchInProgress = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of choices. A couple that come to mind:

Option 1: Create a custom subclass of UIView, set userInteractionEnabled for the view to true, implement touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded, and develop logic that starts a timer and does what you want

Option 2: Create a custom subclass of UIGestureRecognizer that offers the features you want. gesture recognizers have a built in mechanism for notifying a target when interesting events happen. You could create your own that has parameters for the amount of delay before it begins sending messages, and the interval between messages.

Option 2 would take the most research up front, but would give you the most flexible, reusable solution. I have found sample custom UIGestureRecognizer projects on GitHub. One that I worked with a little is the [KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer)

Creating your own gesture recognizer is actually easier than you might think. That's the route I would recommend. It's a good learning experience.